# Find and tar files on Solaris

Tags: unix, find, solaris, tar

I've got a little problem with my bash script. I'm newbie in unix world, so I find it difficult to deal with an exercise. What I have to do is find files on Solaris server with specific name, modified in specific time and archive them in one .tar file. First two points are easy, but I'm having a nightmare with trying to archive it. The thing is, I constantly archive whole tree of file (with file at the end) to .tar file, but I need just a file. My code looks like this:

```
find ~ -name "$maska" -mtime -$dni | xargs -t -L 1 tar -cvf $3 -C
```

where $maska is the name of the file, $dni refers to modification time and $3 is just a archive name. I found out about -C switch, that let's me jump into the folder where desired file is, but when I use it with xargs, it seems just to jump there and do nothing else.

So my question is:

1) is there any possibility of achieving my goal this way?

Please remember, I don't work on gnu tar. And I HAVE TO use commands: tar, find.

Edit: I'd like to specify more my problem. When I use the script for, for example, file a, it should look for it since the point shown in script (it's ~ ) and everything it will find should be in one tar file.

What I got right now is (I'm in /home/me/Scripts):

```
-bash-3.2$ ./Script.sh a 1000 backup
 a /home/me/Program/Test/a/ 0K
 a /home/me/Program/Test/a/a.c 1K
 a /home/me/Program/Test/a/a.out 8K
```

So script has done some packing. Next I want to see my packed file, so:

```
 -bash-3.2$ tar -tf backup 
 /home/me/Program/Test/a/
 /home/me/Program/Test/a/a.c
 /home/me/Program/Test/a/a.out
```

And that's the problem. Tar file have all the paths in it, so if I will untar it, instead of getting just the file I wanted to archive, I will replace them in their old places. For visualisation:

```
-bash-3.2$ ls
Script.sh*   Script.sh~*  backup
-bash-3.2$ tar -xvf backup 
x /home/me/Program/Test/a, 0 bytes, 0 tape blocks
x /home/me/Program/Test/a/a.c, 39 bytes, 1 tape blocks
x /home/me/Program/Test/a/a.out, 7928 bytes, 16 tape blocks
-bash-3.2$ ls
Script.sh*   Script.sh~*  backup
```

That's the problem.

So all I want is to pack all those desired file (a in example above) in one tar file without those paths, so it will simply untar in the directory I run the Script.sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you want but this might be it :

```
find ~ -name "$maska" -mtime -$dni -exec tar cvf $3 {} +
```

Edit: second attempt after your wrote the main issue is the absolute path:

```
( cd ~; find . -name "$maska" -type f -mtime -$dni -exec tar cvf $3 {} + )
```

Edit: third attempt, after you wrote you want no path at all in the archive, `maska` is a directory name and `$3` need to be in the current directory:

```
mkdir ~/foo && \
  find ~ -name "$maska" -type d -mtime -$dni -exec sh -c 'ln -s $1/* ~/foo/' sh {} \; && \
  ( cd ~/foo ; tar chf - * ) > $3 && \
  rm -rf ~/foo
```

Replace `~/foo` by `~/somethingElse` if `~/foo` already exists for some reason.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a solution for my problem. I'll add some more explanation in my first post.

Comment: Well, it's definitely not the solution either. That line makes script do a tar file in ~ and it still has all the paths in it, so untaring it still won't give desired file in the place, where script was launched.

Comment: @Treck Never too late ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
find ~ -name "$maska" -mtime -$dni -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do
   d=$(dirname "$file")
   f=$(basename "$file")
   echo $d: $f      # Show directory and file for debug purposes
   tar -rvf tarball.tar -C"$d" "$f"
done
```

I don't have a Solaris box at hand for testing :-)

Comment: Well, I see how it works, and I really thought that will do, but... Still something is wrong. In more specific words, there is no .tar file anywhere. I checked working directory and ~/tmp/ (which doesn't even exist!). But the "finding" part works, I checked it.So while - do, or tar must be responsible for bug. Also no echo output at all.

Comment: I just used `~/tmp` on my machine so as not to interfere with my own files. I will delete it.

Comment: Yeah, still no response. I guess it should just create tar file called tarball in the current directory, where I run Script. But it does not.

Comment: Maybe add `touch tarball.tar` at the start.

Comment: Just tried this way. After launching Script tarball.tar is as empty as my ex's heart.

Comment: Ok, you can debug it by changing first line to `#!/bin/bash -xv`

Comment: Everything runs smoothly until this part:

+ find /home/me -name a -mtime -5 -print
+ read -d '' file

and that actually is the end of the debugger output. Seems like it doesn't have any output from find command for me.

And by the way, running script with commented pipe and the rest script (just finding) produce following output:

/home/me/Program/Test/a

which is good.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, my assumptions:
1. "one tar file", like you said, and
2. no absolute paths, ie if you backup ~/dir/file, you should be able to test extracting it in /tmp obtaining /tmp/dir/file.

If the problem is the full paths, you should replace

```
find ~ # etc
```

with

```
cd ~ || exit
find . # etc
```

If the tar archive isn't an absolute name, instead, it should be something like

```
(
cd ~ || exit
find . etc etc | xargs tar cf - etc etc
) > $3
```

Explanation
"(...)" runs a subshell, meaning some of the tings you change in there have no effects outside of the parens; the current directory is one of them, so "(cd whatever; foo)" means you run another shell, change **its** current directory, run foo from there, and then you're back in your script which never changed directory.

"cd ~ || exit" is paranoia, it means "cd ~; if that fails, exit".

"." is an alias meaning "the current directory, whatever that is"; play with "find ." vs "find ~" if you don't know what it means, you'll understand it better than if I explained it here.

"tar cf -" means that you create the tar archive on standard output; I **think** the syntax is portable enough, you may have to replace "-" with "/dev/stdout" or whatever works on solaris (the simplest solution is simply "tar", without the "c" command, but it's ugly to read).

The final "> $3", outside of the parens, is output redirection: rather than writing the output to the terminal, you save it into a file.

So the whole script reads like this:
- open a subshell
- change the subshell's current directory to ~
- in the subshell, find the files newer than requested, archive them, and write the contents of the resulting tar archive to standard output
- the subshell's stdout is saved to $3; because the redirection is outside the parens, relative paths are resolved relatively to your script's $PWD, meaning that eg if you run the script from the /tmp directory you'll get a tar archive in the /tmp directory (it would be in ~ if the redirection happened in the subshell).

If I misunderstood your question, the solution doesn't work or the explanation isn't clear let me know (the answer is too long, but I already know that :).

Comment: The first solution keeps whole paths!

And the second one:
tar: can't change directories to ./home/me/Program/Test: No such file or directory

Even if it exists... I would appreciate a bit more explanation from You, of course when You'll have a while ;)

Comment: I simply had dinner, my 3rd option was a brainfart - I'm rewriting it now :)

Comment: Tar works, but still it's got whole parent directory tree... When I untar it, there are still other directories and deep inside them desired file.

I don't mind reading long texts as long, as it will teach me something ;)

Comment: @Treck if you archive ~/Program/Test/a/a.c and extract the result in /tmp you'll get /tmp/Program/Test/a/a.c; did you just want /tmp/a.c?

Comment: @Treck also, "xargs -L 1" means it will run one tar invocation for each file, are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: Exactly, what I need and desire is just simply /tmp/a.c. No other directories between. Well, I've been experimenting with xargs and I am conscious of this "miss". I already removed -L and leave only -t for testing purpose.

Comment: @Treck ok, I thught you only wanted to get rid of "/home/me" - I don't know of any reasonable way to get what you want (Mark Setchell's answer should be close to it); if your tar recognizes the "h" option you can play with that, but it's probably easier (and faster) to use my answer and "flatten" the result after extraction, ie extract in a temporary directory and use then "mv $(find $temporary_directory -type f) /tmp"

Answer (score 0):

The [pax command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7mgs/index.html) will output tar-compatible archives and has the flexibility you need to rewrite pathnames.

```
find ~ -name "$maska" -mtime -$dni | pax -w -x ustar -f "$3" -s '!.*/!!'
```

Here are what the options mean, paraphrasing from the man page:

- -`w` write the contents of the file operands to the standard output (or to the pathname specified by the `-f` option) in an archive format.
- `-x ustar` the output archive format is the extended `tar` interchange format specified in the IEEE POSIX standard.
- `-s '!.*/!!'` Modifies file operands according to the substitution expression, using regular expression syntax. Here, it deletes all characters in each file name from the beginning to the final `/`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But as I said in first post: "And I HAVE TO use commands: tar, find.". But I guess I took something wrong and I got a bad concept of what I should do. I did a version that simply packs everything to folder and tar it, since it's closest I can get with tar. I'm gonna check your code as well.

Comment: OK. `pax` has been in Solaris since Solaris 7, but I understand you may have portability constraints.